# Python block text analyze

Tags: file, dictionary, text

I need to analyze data from files with a format like this:

```
[Something01]
param1=foo
param2=foo
param3=foo

[Something02]
param1=foo
param2=foo
param3=foo
```

I want to put it in a nested dictionary for generating a csv file later like:

```
Device;param1;param2;param3;
Something01;foo;foo;foo
Something02;foo;foo;foo
```

The nested dictionary I want:

```
dic = {
       Something01: {
                      param1: 'foo'
                      param2: 'foo'
                    },
       Something02: {
                      param1: 'foo'
                      param2: 'foo'
                    }
      }
```

I'm new to Python and I don't know where to start. I'll agree more if you give me docs and explanation rather than just writing something.

Comment: From the format, it looks like you're trying to read an INI file. If that's the case, you can try using [Python ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) which does what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [Pranav Prakash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229341/pranav-prakash) pointed out, you can use the ConfigParser package to read the data file and then push the data into dictionary.

Here's an example code. The `json` package is used only for pretty printing.

```python
import json
import ConfigParser

c = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
c.read('test.ini')

dic = {}
for sec in c.sections():
    items = {}
    for k,v in c.items(sec):
        items[k] = v
    dic[sec] = items

print json.dumps(dic, indent=4)
```